# How do I display only ONE textbox under Post not more textboxes?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a posting function like Facebook (post a text, publish a text) and a comment function where you can comment the post. Everything works fine but something disturbs me. If you get the link from the accordingly post, then under **every** post an Textbox appears, not only under the post where you clicked "comment/answer".

Of course I could tell the user that he needs to write the comment under the post where he clicked. But I think this is really laborious. Also I have a Javascript function entering symbols, if you clicked on it. But this doesn't work. I think that the problem is that under every post a textbox appears. That's the code.

```
<html><head></head><body>
$exampleid = "7";
<?php   echo '<a href="link.php?id='$exampleid'"><input type="submit" id="answer" name="answer" value="Antworten"></a><br>';
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
?>
```

Now there's the part with the textbox, the form, which appears under **every** post, not only under the post where you've clicked on the link:

```
<form action="" method="post"><textarea name="textfield" id="textfield"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="send"/></form>
```

I've tried with `<textarea style="position: absolute; text-align: center;">` and with `<form style="position:absolute; text-align: center;"` but thats just for the text xD. [Photo with Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfW5T.png)

Comment: bit offtopic but this looks like a terrible code :D

Comment: @Dwza yeah, lot of people are telling me that my code looks terrible, but the most important thing for me is that the code works

Comment: this is true. thats why i sayed offtopic :D you really shoud get used of MVC and may have some looks in template systems like twig or smarty. but this is just a side info and actually has none to do with solving your problem :) But to your question, ist kind of hard to get the point without a behaving sample or some... could you provide some kinfe of fiddle? since there is php used, may use https://replit.com/languages/php to make a testable fiddle :)

Comment: ok. well, but do you have an Idea how I can solve my display topic?

Comment: just like i sayed, providing a fiddle would help to get an answere for your question.